# How can I have more than only two command-line flags controlling the same behavior?

Tags: go, command-line-arguments

In Go, I know how to use the `github.com/pborman/getopt` package to perform `getopt`-like command-line parsing.

However, this package only seems to be able to support one string version and one rune version of each command-line option. Sometimes I want more than simply two ways to specify an option. For example, for a hypothetical program called `prog`, I'd like the following to all perform the exact, same function:

```
prog -r [other args]
prog -R [other args]
prog --recurse [other args]
prog --recursive [other args]
```

I know that I can do something like the following and just test for the value of each of the variables `optRecurse` and `optRecursive` ...

```
optRecurse   := getopt.BoolLong("recurse",   'r', "run recursively")
optRecursive := getopt.BoolLong("recursive", 'R', "run recursively")
```

However, ideally, I'd like to make one, single call that will give me one value for any of these four possibilities.

I want something that works similarly to Ruby's `OptionParser` package with regard to more than two possibilities for any given command-line option. Here's a Ruby example ...

```rb
$isRecursive = false
parser = OptionParser.new {
  |opts|
  opts.on('-r', '-R', '--recurse', '--recursive') {
    |arg|
    # All four possibilities are handled with one, single "opts.on" block.
    $isRecursive = true
  }
  # ... etc. ...
}
```

I'm relatively new to Go, and I may very well have overlooked something in my searches for an answer to this question.

Comment: I doubt it’s builtin. From a design viewpoint, why would a library optimize for such an odd case which is so simple to handle in your own code?

Comment: It's because most other argument-parsing libraries which are in use in other languages (such as Ruby and Python) do indeed make this exact optimization ... and this was done for the convenience of the developers who use their languages. My reason for posting this question is to see whether anyone might have also decided to offer this same convenience to Go developers. I guess not. And **PS**: I don't care whether it's built in or it's a 3rd-party package.

Comment: [viper](https://github.com/spf13/viper) support it

Comment: Thank you! I can see that viper offers argument parsing plus extensive program configuration features, and all this is very useful. I also found something called "argparse" which focuses solely on arguments, and it offers the similar kinds of command-line argument-parsing capabilities that are offered for other languages such as Ruby and Python. Since I'm mostly just looking for argument parsing at the moment, I'm going to use argparse. For more details, see my "Answer", which  I am currently in the process of writing and which therefore will be available soon.

Comment: I updated my "Answer", because the "argparse" package that I originally mentioned there is no longer supported. But I found a different package which also offers the same capability of having more than two ways to specify any given command-line option, and that other package is now what I'm describing in my "Answer".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion, there is nothing "odd" about offering more than two ways to specify any given command-line option.

The `github.com/clagraff/argparse` package that I originally mentioned here in this "Answer" is no longer being supported. However, I found a more modern and still supported package that I can use which offers that exact capability in a manner which is similar to what's offered in argument-parsing packages for other languages such as Ruby and Python: `github.com/tcler/cmdline-go/cmdline`.

Here is a sample program which illustrates how this can work in Go ...

```
package main                  

import (
    "fmt";
    "os";
    "github.com/tcler/cmdline-go/cmdline";
)

func main() {
    var nargv []string = os.Args[1:]
    var cli cmdline.Cmdline

    var options = []cmdline.Option {
        {Help: "Options:"},
        {Names: "r R recurse recursive", Argtype: cmdline.N, Help: "Run recursively"},
    }

    cli = cmdline.Parse(options, nargv)

    has_invalid := false
    for _, v := range cli.InvalidOptions {
        if !has_invalid {
            fmt.Println()
        }
        fmt.Println(v)
        has_invalid = true
    }
    if has_invalid {
        fmt.Println()
        cmdline.GetUsage(options)
        os.Exit(1)
    }

    recursivemode := cli.GetOptionArgString("r")
    fmt.Printf("recursive mode: \"%s\"\n", recursivemode)
}
```

I can run the program in all four of the following ways, and it behaves the same in each case ...

```
% go run prog.go -r
% go run prog.go -R
% go run prog.go --recurse
% go run prog.go --recursive
```

In all four of these these cases, it always outputs the following:

```
recursive mode: "set"
```

If I run without any option (*i.e.*, simply `go run prog.go`), it outputs this:

```
recursive mode: ""
```

And if I run with any other command-line argument, such as `-x` for example, it fails as follows:

```
% go run prog.go -x

option: 'x' undefined

Options:
     -r -R --recurse --recursive
                               Run recursively

[ plus some other "help" text ]
```

So, now I can write Go programs which allow more than two ways to specify any command-line option.